# MYSQL - group by more than one column Complication

Tags: mysql

I have so many record in database, i am trying to get data by group by, but my problem is if use group by one column like right now i am using group by name but then other column not showing right data

```
SELECT 
      IF( user_org.active = '0', 
             CONCAT(user_org_profiles.name, ' (disabled)' ),
             user_org_profiles.name ) AS name, 
      user_org.oid AS id, 
      IF( 149 =149 AND user_org_profiles_ext.account != '', 
             user_org_profiles_ext.account, 
             user_org.oid ) AS dealerid 
   FROM 
      user_org 
         LEFT JOIN user_org_profiles 
            ON user_org.oid = user_org_profiles.oid 
         LEFT JOIN user_org_profiles_ext 
            ON user_org.oid = user_org_profiles.oid 
   WHERE 
          user_org.active = '1' 
      AND user_org_profiles.name != '' 
   GROUP BY 
      name
```

i am getting this output

[image]

because i am using group by name only so that's by dealerid is same but i need output like this 
[image]

Here Some actual data

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_org` (
`oid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`suffix` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`orgkey` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`gid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`oid`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=902 ;
INSERT INTO `user_org` (`oid`, `active`, `suffix`, `orgkey`, `gid`) VALUES
(1, 0, 'wire1', 'Aahsoas_-_', 3),
(2, 1, 'int-ohs2', 'Interiors_with_', 3),
(3, 1, 'artah3', 'Ar_Sp_-_U', 3),
(4, 0, ' 4', 'Aqc_Pls_&', 3),
(5, 1, 'goc5', 'Arc_pa_&_Le', 3),
(6, 1, 'copes6', 'Coo_Pc', 3),
(7, 1, 'cms', 'CMSol', 3),
(8, 0, 'hotl8', 'Clool', 3),
(9, 0, 'tet9', 'Coome_', 3),
(10, 0, ' 10', 'Tore', 3),
(11, 0, 'kco11', 'Nie_I', 3),
(12, 0, ' 12', 'Hil_In', 3),
(14, 0, ' 14', 'Brough_En', 3),
(15, 0, 'Letbs15', 'Leisme_Ho', 3),
(16, 0, 'telt16', 'Whit_me', 3);
```

2nd table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_org_profiles` (
`oid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`oid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `user_org_profiles` (`oid`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Aaas - ko'),
(2, 'Int and ahs'),
(3, 'Art- ah'),
(4, 'Aqls & as'),
(5, 'Art pure'),
(6, 'Colo Ps'),
(7, 'CMS Cons'),
(8, 'Clearas'),
(9, 'Colare'),
(10, 'Thre'),
(11, 'Ninc.'),
(12, 'Hiltd.'),
(14, 'Breatd.'),
(15, 'Leisbs'),
(16, 'Whitre');
```

3rd table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_org_profiles_ext` (
`oid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`account` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`oid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `user_org_profiles_ext` (`oid`, `account`) VALUES
(1,'C-0006'),
(2,'C-0056'),
(3,'C-0030'),
(4,' '),
(5,'C-0016'),
(6,'C-0246'),
(7,'C-0050'),
(8,'C-0037'),
(9,'COL001'),
(10,' '),
(11,'C-0157'),
(12,'HIL002'),
(14,' '),
(15,'LEI01U'),
(16,' ');
```

Comment: Please. No pictures.

Comment: @Strawberry now i added actual data with table sturcture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing to "Group by 1" where 1 represents the ordinal column in the list vs the actual NAME column of the data..

or just paste the whole first column via

```
group by
   IF( user_org.active = '0', 
             CONCAT(user_org_profiles.name, ' (disabled)' ),
             user_org_profiles.name )
```

You have a left-join for your user_org_profiles, but add AND to your where clause turning it into an INNER JOIN.  Also, your IF( 149 =149 AND ... would always have the first part as valid and could be excluded, just leave the other part of the condition.

Finally, since you are ally are not doing any aggregates, I would just ignore the GROUP BY and just change to distinct

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      IF( user_org.active = '0', 
             CONCAT(user_org_profiles.name, ' (disabled)' ),
             user_org_profiles.name ) AS name, 
      user_org.oid AS id, 
      IF(    user_org_profiles_ext.account = '', 
             user_org.oid, user_org_profiles_ext.account ) AS dealerid 
   FROM 
      user_org 
         JOIN user_org_profiles 
            ON user_org.oid = user_org_profiles.oid 
         LEFT JOIN user_org_profiles_ext 
            ON user_org.oid = user_org_profiles_ext.oid 
   WHERE 
          user_org.active = '1'
      AND user_org_profiles.name != ''
```

FINAL RESULT ...

Per sample data and actually trying the query, result was due to an incorrect JOIN clause.  The second instance was joining to the USER_ORG_PROFILES and not USER_ORG_PROFILES_EXT.

Comment: Still not working, okay I will try post some actual data

Comment: because of some tables also contain confidential data of client so its hard to post here publically

Comment: @user3712320, I understand confidential data, but the pictures of the ex: 8-10 entries, even if you change the data to "bogus company a", oid=1 status = "O", name = "test".... etc... Just keep CONTEXT of the data the same of the few fields you are trying to capture.  If there are multiple entries for a company in the profiles or profiles_ext, show multiple records there too.  Context the same, LIVE Data make it up.  And use spaces for alignment, not tabs when you enter the data.

Comment: @user3712320, revised... your SECOND Left-outer join was to the user_org_profiles.oid and SHOULD have been user_org_profiles_EXT.oid... Try that, otherwise it was creating a Cartesian result

Comment: omg i am a such a fool, what a silly mistake i did which i couldn't noticed, thank you so much

Comment: can you put this as an answer

Comment: @user3712320, it IS an answer from above, you can upvote/ check this and I'll just update the content at the end...